# Doctrine result field_as_object dropped

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am doing a simple doctrine query to select all values from my table. In this table I have a user foreign key which is actually an id of my user entity. The problem is that when I use something like

```
->getArrayResult();
```

or

```
->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

I see all fields in the result except my user field. I can see it only if I var_dump

```
->getResult();
```

but I need an array in this case, not an object. My user field is as follows:

```
/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\User
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $user;
```

Any ideas how to get it and why it gets dropped out of the query result? I would not like to foreach the returned result again and convert all the objects to plain array as it would be slow.

Thank you.

**UPD** I tried to use Joins like this:

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT a FROM 'AppBundle:Audit' a 
              INNER JOIN 'AppBundle:User' u 
              WITH a.user = u.id");
$query = $em->createQuery($sql)
                //->setParameters($parameters)
                //->setHint(Query::HINT_INCLUDE_META_COLUMNS, true)
                ->getArrayResult();
```

but still cannot get other user data.

Comment: I think you are looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836815/how-to-get-association-foreign-key-ids-in-doctrine-2-without-loading-the-associa

Comment: Yes, works great, but is it possible to acc3ess properties of my user object? Say if I want to get not only id, but username, email of the user as well?

Comment: then check other options http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#object-hydration

Comment: Unfortunately other options did not work((. I tried to use JOIN but still cannot get user data

Comment: don't you think your selection should be obvious like ` SELECT a,u FROM...` http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins

Comment: Yes, I finally did the same, but had to manually access all fields that I needed. I thought it was possible to automatically serialize all fields, including those referenced by foreign key.