# Force 'fetch joined' relations to include IDENTITY of their ManyToOne relations using HYDRATE_ARRAY?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, php-7

I have a query in which I'm joining a number of tables to my original Person entity. A `Person` may have multiple `Child` relations (OneToMany), and a `Child` may have a `School` they go to (ManyToOne). Problem is, I don't need the entire `School` entity that connects to each child, only their `id`, which is already stored on `Child`.

I'm using a `Paginator` to iterate through the results and I use HYDRATE_ARRAY to reduce overhead of the ORM parsing data to entity objects. But the `id` fields of unfetched relations are not returned this way, and thus, the School `id` isn't either.

I may join the `School` entity too, but since the identity is already stored on the `Child` records, I don't see why I should further reduce performance by having the database join another table. Fetching results as entity objects would also solve the problem, but also at the cost of performance. How can I get the `id` to apper the results without having to unnecessarily join the the `School` entity or having to hydrate the results as objects?

```
$query = $em->getRepository(Entity\Person::class)->createQueryBuilder('p');

$query
  ->select([
    'p as person',
    'w.name as workplace_name',
    'c',
  ])
  ->leftJoin('p.children', 'c') //Entity\Child
  ->leftJoin('p.workplace', 'w') //Entity\Company
  //...

;
$paginator = new Paginator($query);
$paginator->getQuery()
  ->setHydrationMode(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

Comment: AFAIK you need to use native query with result set mapping to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_INCLUDE_META_COLUMNS**](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.6/Doctrine/ORM/Query.html) to include the foreign key column values in the result:

```
$paginator->getQuery()
->setHint(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_INCLUDE_META_COLUMNS, true)
->setHydrationMode(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

which:

> The includeMetaColumns query hint causes meta columns like foreign keys and discriminator columns to be selected and returned as part of the query result.

Reference

- [Doctrine\ORM\Query documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.6/Doctrine/ORM/Query.html)
- [How to get association foreign key IDs in Doctrine 2 without loading the associated object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836815/how-to-get-association-foreign-key-ids-in-doctrine-2-without-loading-the-associa)
- [Getting only ID from entity relations without fetching whole object in Doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139970/getting-only-id-from-entity-relations-without-fetching-whole-object-in-doctrine)